# Change Pictures without the drawable image

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I was given a task but im not sure how to go about it. My job is to create a button in android, an image button ideally. 
i have to be able to modify the color of it (red, green, yellow), display a number on top of it or as a background (random value from 1-1000). 
The only way i can think of doing this is by creating multiple drawable images one for each number. The issue there is that i would need to create one for each color which would be around 3000 images. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why not set the button text to the number and change color of the text accordingly?

Comment: I thought about doing that but I was thinking of creating something like the current message application has that shows the number of messages that are unread.

Comment: And have you tried anything so far to get there? If yes, post the code to show what you have done and what the output is. Also, mention how the output is different from what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways resolve your problem:

- You can show background color of button & use Text of button to display Number
- Or if you want to use image drawble --> Create array id of image-drawable. And change background image of button when random execute. (Still create one view-object)